# running SQL after successful upload with jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am way out of my comfort zone here and could use some help. I am using the jQuery-File-Upload plugin to upload files to directory. On the success of the upload I would like to run an SQL query to my database. Where do I do this? Is it with the callbacks?

I am using the `upload.class.php`

Comment: You do the query in your php file.

Comment: Yeah, I can handle that. I just need it on successful upload only.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your file is uploaded on the server with the function [is_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) or [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
If these return TRUE you can running your query.