# Jquery File Upload : Database call after successful images upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using jQuery file upload for file uploads with MVC and Web API. Using the default behaviour singleFileUploads = true  (By default each file of a selection is uploaded using an individual
/request for XHR type uploads).

I am trying to save total number of images and some other data in final database insert call once all the images uploaded to server is completed. 
The other problem is web server doesnt have access to file server, only app server can save and read images from file server.

I know similar question already there but both have different environments and issues.
[running SQL after successful upload with jQuery-File-Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905195/running-sql-after-successful-upload-with-jquery-file-upload)

Here is code : I tried using all callback functions done, completed and
 finished but every function gets call after each file upload. i am trying to call SaveDataDB() only once when all file uploads completed.

```
$(function () {

    $form = $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        singleFileUploads: true,
        sequentialUploads:false,
        url: "/FileUpload/Upload",
        add: function (e, data) {
            $("#btnStart").on("click", function () {
                data.submit();
            })
        },
        completed: function (e, data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/FileUpload/SaveDataDB",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        },
    }).bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) { alert("Message", "Title"); })
      .bind('fileuploadfinished', function (e, data) { alert("fileuploadfinished", "Title") })
      **.bind('fileuploadstop', function (e, data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/FileUpload/SaveDataDB",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: TotalFiles,
                success: function (data) {
                };**

});
```

MVC Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Upload()
    {
        var resultList = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

        var CurrentContext = HttpContext;

        filesHelper.UploadAndShowResults(CurrentContext, resultList);
        JsonFiles files = new JsonFiles(resultList);
        bool isEmpty = !resultList.Any();
        if (isEmpty)
        {
            return Json("Error ");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(files);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveDataDB()
    {
        return Json(new { status = "Success", message = "Success" });
    }
```

Comment: why don't you call it upon success upload , so inside `Upload()` function in your mvc, call `SaveDataDB()` on success save.

Comment: success function will gets called multiple times for each file upload request same as done.

Comment: Each form submission causes only one file upload, is that right?

Comment: No it can upload multiple images but each file uploads using single request

Answer (score 0):

hi instead of making two different actions try merge them in one

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Upload()
    {
        var resultList = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

    var CurrentContext = HttpContext;

    filesHelper.UploadAndShowResults(CurrentContext, resultList);
    JsonFiles files = new JsonFiles(resultList);
    bool isEmpty = !resultList.Any();
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        return Json("Error ");
    }
    else
    {
        //Put the SaveToDb Code here 
        return Json(new{files=files,success="success",message ="success");
    }
}
```

Comment: again same problem , calls for each file upload.

Comment: got the solution , bind event fileuploadstop . this event gets called after file uploads completed.I have edit the question to add this code.